# Using WCF over externally managed TCP sockets

Tags: c#, wcf

Today we are using WCF's `NetTcpBinding` to communicate between peers in our system. The communication is bidirectional: each peer has channels opened against the other peers.

We are now looking into extending our architecture and introduce two "types" of peers: "public" peers are accessible over the public Internet, while "internal" peers are behind NAT. The impact of this is that an internal peer can establish TCP connections to a public peer, but the reverse is impossible. Therefore, public peers can no longer establish connections to internal peers.

Since TCP connections are symmetric (once established), my plan was to have the internal peer establish all the required TCP sockets against the public peer, and then have the public peer use some of these sockets to establish channels to the internal peer. However, when using NetTcpBinding, WCF manages the TCP sockets for me.

Will I have to write a new transport to implement this behavior, or is there an alternative way?

Comment: You can also just forward the appropriate port(s) through your firewall, to enable incoming external connections to reach your internal network. You can't guarantee external peers to not be behind NAT, so initiating the connection from your side will run into the same problems - which can be solved by again forwarding the port(s) through the firewall, but now at the client side. For each client.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are correct that I can use port forwarding in the NAT, but it will require more configuration on the "internal" side. The two types of peers are used by two very different types of customers: for the "internal" type, I prefer to require as few configuration changes as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into SSH forwarding.

Comment: It is interesting, but it says that "this specific method only works for outgoing TCP connections" - I also need to allow incoming connections (to the so-called "internal" peer), and as I mentioned in a previous comment, "internal" peers are used by customers for which I prefer to require as little setup as possible. Specifically, I want to avoid having to open Firewall/NAT ports.